# Unit Test public methods related to a private collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

My class has a private lazy dictionary and some method to interact with it like this

```
public class MyClass : IExampleClass
{
    private Lazy<Dictionary<string, IMyObject>> myObjects = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, IMyObject>>();
    private Dictionary<string, IMyObject> MyObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return myObjects.Value;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass()
    {}

    public void RegisterObject(string name, IMyObject object)
    {
        logger.LogInfo("Executed RegisterObject etc.");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == false && object != null && MyObjects.ContainsKey(name) == false)
        {
             MyObjects.Add(name, object);
        }
        else
        {
             logger.LogWarning("Cannot register the object because etc.");
        }
    }

    public IMyObject GetObject(string name)
    {
        logger.LogInfo("Executed GetObject etc.");

        IMyObject obj = null;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == false)
        {
            Objects.TryGetValue(name, out obj);
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

This is something useful because sometimes happens that some of the inserted objects are null so i prevent any furter damage avoiding adding them.
Now i'm facing a problem during the testing phase (i know, shame on me, i write code before test) because i'm forced to use both methods inside the same test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTest 
{
    [Test]
    public void RegisterObject_WithNullNameAndNullObject_DoNothing()
    {
        //Arrange
        string inputName = null;
        IMyObject inputObject = null;
        IExampleClass sut = new MyClass();

        //Act
        sut.RegisterObject(inputName, inputObject);

        //Assert
        IMyObject actualValue = sut.GetObject(inputName);
        Assert.IsNull(actualValue);
    }

    ...
}
```

On top of that how can i handle the test where i'm trying to insert an element already in the dictionary?

```
    [Test]
    public void RegisterObject_AlreadyInserted_DoNothing()
    {
        //Arrange
        string inputName = "test";
        IMyObject inputObject = A.Dummy<IMyObject>();
        IExampleClass sut = new MyClass();

        // ??? 
        sut.RegisterObject(inputName, inputObject);
        // how can i effectively test the method if i'm using it more than once???

        //Act
        sut.RegisterObject(inputName, inputObject);

        //Assert
        IMyObject actualValue = sut.GetObject(inputName);

        // ???
        Assert.AreEqual(inputObject, actualValue);
        // What i've tested here? The fact that the dictionary contains
        // the object doesn't mean that the second call of RegisterObject
        // is ignored.
    }
```

So at end i'm asking:

1. Is correct to test RegisterObject calling GetObject inside it?
2. How can i arrange the dictionary if i have to test that the second insertion is ignored?

On a side note, i have 7 separate tests for RegisterObject:

- RegisterObject_WithNullNameAndNullObject_DoNothing()
- RegisterObject_WithNullNameAndValidObject_DoNothing()
- RegisterObject_WithEmptyNameAndNullObject_DoNothing()
- RegisterObject_WithEmptyNameAndValidObject_DoNothing()
- RegisterObject_WithValidNameAndNullObject_DoNothing()
- RegisterObject_WithValidNameAndValidObject_RegisterObject()
- RegisterObject_AlreadyInserted_DoNothing()

It's overkill? Too many test for this simple behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is correct to test RegisterObject calling GetObject inside it?

Given that all we know about the public interface of `MyClass` is that it has `RegisterObject` and `GetObject`, I don't think there's anything else you can do.
Even if you could do something else, I wouldn't. You want to ensure that the class behaves in a certain way for its consumers, so use it like a consumer does. That's how you can tell whether it's doing its job.

> How can i arrange the dictionary if i have to test that the second insertion is ignored?

Think about this from the consumer's point of view. What do you want to happen? It seems that you want to show that if you insert a second object under an existing key that the method silently succeeds, but that the value that's stored is the original one. How can we tell what's stored? By calling `GetObject`. So I think the test you had is good, but I'd use a different value to insert. That way you can tell whether anything was changed. If `GetObject` returns the original value, your methods did the right thing.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about using a different object on the insert to verify any change. I'm not entirely fine about using `GetObject` inside `RegisterObject`'s tests but can't find any other way to do that.